# What is the difference between char[5] and char[10]?

Tags: c++

I know,that in char[], in between square brackets we write the lenght of character.

For example, if we write char[10], it should give us 10 characters or less.

But, in my code, where I input my name "Ramunas"(which is 7 characters), instead of giving me 5 characters(Ramun), it still ends up giving "Ramunas". Why does that happen?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a[5];
    cout<<"Hello, enter your name: "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is because the program has undefined behavior. You overwrote the memory beyond the array.

Comment: Note that "Ramunas" is 8 characters when you count the null terminator character. Also note that "Ramūnas" is potentially even more chars in unicode encoding.

Comment: Here is an example. Everything seems correct but you overwrote the variable `i`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/p2LpOvIrVat3laaa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a buffer overflow. `cin` only knows the address of the array and does not check the size of allocated (or not) memory behind this address.

`cout` also does not perform any check here. It starts reading chars at the provided address until it finds '\0'.

You can prevent buffer overflow in this case by explicitly limiting the number of chars that `cin` accepts.

```
cin >> std::setw(5) >> a
```